# Android Studio 2.2.3 - minSdk(API21) > deviceSdk(API17)

Tags: android-studio

I get this error when I try to run an android tablet as an emulator. Does it mean my device is older than the Android Studio version ?
[image: Deployment Target]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, it means you are developing an app that requires API 21 or bigger to run, and your device has API 17. Open your Project Settings and change min requirements to 17 and see if it runs. If you're not using some special control, object or method, maybe you will be successful on this, and will get your app requiring API 17 as minimal base to run. Case negative, you will have to investigate where the problem lives, may be a property, object or method. Luck.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will be here waiting if you have additional doubts. Try to change what I said and see what happens. Maybe a couple of problem will raise and you will be forced to workaround one by one... adapting, searching alternatives, googling... have luck!